# Using Geoserver to serve Tiles in zoom/x/y.png format?

Tags: geoserver, tile-server

I have an application that receives tiles from an OSM tile server using the url format URL/zoom/x/y.png . I'm looking into using GeoServer instead of the OSM tile server. I understand that GeoServer uses the WMS standard.

Is it possible to serve tiles using GeoServer with the endpoint url format similar to the OSM tile server?

Comment: Geoserver comes with integrated GeoWebCache which can serve tiles through many different protocols http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/services/index.html TMS is closest to the format that OSM is using but the tile naming schema is different. Something about this is in the OSM wiki http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TMS

Comment: here's hoping you receive this. Did you get this to work, I'm doing the exact same thing and GeoWebCache is returning blank pngs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Link19, I basically flipped the Y coordinates before I sent the request to Geoserver. I am essentially changing my request from the OSM standard to the WMS standard. You can refer to the link http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/converting-tms-tile-coordinates-to-googlebingosm-tile-coordinates/ for an example.