# Tiles are blank when Using GeoWebCache TMS to get zoom/x/y.png files

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, tile-map-service

I have a similar requirement to [Using Geoserver to serve Tiles in zoom/x/y.png format?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/97878/115), so my existing application works with OSM server and I've been trying to switch it to use our local GeoServer for the tiles.

I've implemented the Y coordinate conversion detailed in the question above, but that has not solved my issue, in that I am being returned empty PNGs from the server. Specifically i'm using this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/osm:osm/16/32764/43740.png
```

which I am expecting to be a tile in Isle of Dogs, London UK. [This tile from OSM.](http://tile.openstreetmap.org/16/32764/21795.png)

I'm using an OSM download deployed in potgis, and previews from the web interface do seem to work so it just seems like using the TMS URL's are going wrong somehow.

The one thing I'm unsure of if is the server will generate the tile if it's not already in the cache, or if it only serves tiles if they already exist?

Is there a way to make it generate them if this is the case?

---

I've just tried this:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/osm:osm/1/1/1.png
```

And it produces this:

[image: tile]

So it looks like the layer is correct, I should have mentioned I only have the UK so my guess is that my co-ordinate conversion is not correct, so I'm looking in to that but I thought I had converted Correctly.

Comment: It should generate and cache tiles if not available, but that assumes some configuration you haven't described.  You need to tell us more about your configuration. What does http://localhost:8080/geowebcache/service/tms/1.0.0/ show? How did you load the data into your geoserver? Is the layer really called osm:osm? Please click edit below the question, and provide some more background for your question.

Comment: Ok I've edited it a bit. I, by fluke, discovered it may be working by typing random numbers in to the URL. I should mention that I haven't actually linked my application p to the geoserver machine yet I was just trying out URL's based on the system output from my application becasue Ironically I though integrating them when it wasn't working would have been a waste of time.